# C++ Как решить проблему с записью числового значения в структуру?

Tags: c++, структуры

Почему вот эта строка работает и записывает нужное мне значение в `mas_Z[kodS-1].god_r`:

```
scanf("%s", mas_Z[kodS-1].god_r);
```

А вот эта строка после выполнения ничего не записывает в `mas_Z[kodS-1].o_fizika`:

```
scanf("%d", &mas_Z[kodS-1].o_fizika);
```

Вот этот элемент `mas_Z[].god_r` типа `char[4]`.
А вот этот элемент `mas_Z[].o_fizika` типа `double`.

Проблема в том, что программа вылетает на моменте записи строки `mas_Z[kodS-1].o_fizika`. Для решения проблемы с велетом, я заменил её на `&mas_Z[kodS-1].o_fizika`, но теперь после выполнения она пуста.

**Вопрос**

Почему `&mas_Z[kodS-1].o_fizika` не записывает значения? Как решить данную проблему с записью числовых данных?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для чтения значений типа `double` в `scanf` следует использовать спецификатор формата `%lf`

```
scanf("%lf", &mas_Z[kodS-1].o_fizika);
```

Спецификатор формата `%d` предназначен для чтения знаковых целых чисел и требует аргумента типа `int *`. Вы же передаете туда `double *`. Поведение не определено.